# Creating a virtual HID device

Tags: virtual, hid, wdk

I'd like to create a virtual HID device (emulate it with a driver).

It must be visible to clients that implement standard HID detection:

- Call HidD_GetHidGuid() – Get the HID
  device class GUID
- Call SetupDiGetClassDevs() – Get a
  handle to a set of devices which
  implement the HID interface
- Call SetupDiEnumDeviceInterfaces() –
  For each device in the returned set
  of devices, obtain the interface
  information for all exposed HID
  interfaces.
- Call
  SetupDiGetDeviceInterfaceDetail() –
  For each interface obtained in the
  previous call, get the detailed
  information block for that interface.
  This detailed information includes
  the string that can be passed to
  CreateFile() to open a handle to the
  device
- Call SetupDiDestroyDeviceInfoList() –
  Free up the device information set
  that was obtained in the call to
  SetupDiGetClassDevs().

The device should also support reading, so CreateFile / ReadFile would return data supplied by me from the driver.

I don't really know where to begin, as I don't have a lot of exp. in kernel dev. :(

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Some people have had luck with the vmulti project as a base http://code.google.com/p/vmulti/

Answer (score 2):

You sholud write a driver, then use `DevCon` (Device Console Tool) with `install` option.

---

`cmdInstall`:

A variation of cmdUpdate to install a driver when there is no associated hardware. It creates a new root-enumerated device instance and associates it with a made up hardware ID specified on the command line (which should correspond to a hardware ID in the INF). This cannot be done on a remote machine or in the context of Wow64.

---

http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowshardware/DevCon-Sample-4e95d71c

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff544707%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff544780%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Comment: In that case, wont it be possible just to start a new instance of the default hid driver and then using something like libusb or usb4java to interact with the driver?

Answer (score 0):

see the vhidmini ddk sample driver. It was in the version 1830 DDK but is not in the latest version. alternatively the hidfake sample in Oney's book.

See http://www.microsoft.com/mspress/books/sampchap/6262.aspx